# Django: allow a FloatField or an IntegerField in an input form?

Tags: django

I have a Django model with a field for price:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The issue is that my users might enter a price as 245 or as 245.00, and I want the system to be able to handle either.

Can I do something clever to allow this?

Comment: And it does not work? `float(245)` is `245.00` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to do anything at all. A float doesn't have to have a floating-point component - `245` is just as valid a float as `245.00`.

I would second maikhoepfel's recommendation that you don't use floats for prices, though. Floating point isn't able to represent certain decimal values exactly - this is a limitation of the standard IEEE floating-point algorithm. However, I'd recommend you use [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) instead, as this is ideal for values with a fixed number of decimal places, like prices.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in dealing with prices usually dictate that you should be using an IntegerField anyway, because you might run into funky rounding/limited precision errors otherwise. Just divide/multiply by 100.